# jQuery parseDynamic causes errors on page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the jquery plugin parseDynamic from here: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

to apply validation to dynamic elements in ASP.NET MVC 3

however it seems to show the following error when it is run: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Any ideas what the problem is? It seems as though the script is trying to apply validation to fields that don't have the data- attributes and so therfore breaks as it's missing the correct parameters.

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code where you are using it?

Comment: Well it's just called using: ` $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.uiModalContent');` And `.uiModalContent` is the container for the form. The validation does get applied so it's working, but that error causes other scripts to break.

Comment: Have you tried `$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.uiModalContent input[data-val]');`? What version of jQuery are you using?